# Will HP Touchpad keyboard work with Windows PC?

Tags: drivers, keyboard, bluetooth, touchpad

The HP Touchpad Keyboard, designed for use with WebOS devices, looks like a neat, well-made and relatively cheap Bluetooth keyboard that would work well with a Windows media PC, however I'm not sure if it would require a specific driver to work with Windows and if so, does such a thing exist?

Comment: http://forums.palm.com/t5/HP-TouchPad-Software-Hardware/bd-p/touchpad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm typing this message from that very keyboard right now. Not all of the controls work by default, such as adjust brightness, but it works solidly enough.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will. It is a bog standard Bluetooth keyboard using the HID profile.

Comment: Thanks.  Is this from first hand experience?

Comment: Not for this exact model, but, I have used others and just read the manual on their website / reviews.

Answer (score 0):

Download SetPoint from Logitech.

Go to http://www.logitech.com/en-us/584/3131?osid=14&bit=32

and click software downloads on the right to download the SetPoint software.  SetPoint should get the proper drivers you need.

Comment: Why would Logitech drivers help?  Are they the OEM?  Also, see William Hilsum's answer.

Comment: My apologies, for some reason I thought this was a logitech product.